# Admin privileges from google apps user

Tags: django, google-apps, google-provisioning-api

i would need to get detailed admin privileges from google apps user. From Provisioning API the maximum I can know if the user is superadmin. But I want to know if the user can modify user accounts, to add users, edit users, etc. When i have a user_feed i can find in user_feed.login.admin whether admin is true or false. Is there any possibility to find this out?

Something I have seen in Audit API, but this is not for me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to determine if a user is a delegated admin and has rights to create / update / read / delete users short of trying these operations. Obviously if user_feed.login.admin is true then the user is a super admin and has all of these rights.

I'd suggest you simply design your application to catch errors that occur when non-privileged users attempt these operations and display an error explaining what rights need to be granted to the user to proceed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It's a shame that it does not work that way. Programmatically modify user permissions would be great.